# GRUB menu is always displayed - Ubuntu 12.10 with full disk encryption

Tags: grub2, 12.10

**UPDATE:** It seems to have been fixed now, I am no longer getting the Grub menu, please mark this as closed.

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed with full disk encryption (fresh install), the issue is that the GRUB menu is always displayed, I am not able to set the timeout to 0 and default it to Ubuntu. I only have one OS installed, there is no need for the GRUB menu, also there is no timer on the menu, i.e its displayed forever until I select Ubuntu. I tried updating the GRUB config **/etc/default/grub** to set the timeout to 0, but nothing works :(

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

The contents of */boot/grub/grub.cfg*

```
~ ➔ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if loadfont unicode ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_IN
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=0
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-72be0f39-6fe6-43dd-8ea0-314c73e8e238' {
recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-72be0f39-6fe6-43dd-8ea0-314c73e8e238' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-advanced-72be0f39-6fe6-43dd-8ea0-314c73e8e238' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-recovery-72be0f39-6fe6-43dd-8ea0-314c73e8e238' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
    fi
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 53782a70-4418-4b61-a7fc-a147ba166ca1
    fi
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
if [ "x${timeout}" != "x-1" ]; then
  if keystatus; then
    if keystatus --shift; then
      set timeout=-1
    else
      set timeout=0
    fi
  else
    if sleep --interruptible 3 ; then
      set timeout=0
    fi
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you run `sudo update-grub` after you edited the `/etc/default/grub` file? The changes won't have any effect unless you do that.

Comment: Yes,, I did :-)

Comment: Okay :-) Do you think you could post the content of your /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Comment: Added it to the original post, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

maybe grub customizer will do, try and manage settings with admin rights

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer && sudo
  apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

  sudo grub-customizer

[image]

Comment: Is Grub customizer there for 12.10? sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
[sudo] password for asp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grub-customizer

Comment: well i have it working on 12.10..it seems  you need to add new release repository for it. at least you could try http://www.noobslab.com/2012/06/install-grub-customizer-257-in.html